# Algorithm not populating array

Tags: php, arrays

Using the script below, I am trying to execute two queries which store the output from each stored-procedure in two arrays.

The first array is being populated with data while the second is remaining empty. However, if I edit the script to only process the second stored-procedure, this works fine.

Can anybody let me know what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<?php

$host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$user = 'xxxx';
$password = '';
$dbName = 'xxxxx';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $user, $password);

if (!$dbh)
{
    die("Error While Connecting to Database");
}

$query1 = 'CALL getRowSet1';
$query2 = 'CALL getRowSet2';

try
{
    $rowSet1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $rowSet1->execute();
    $rowSet2 = $dbh->prepare($query2);
    $rowSet2->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$results_1 = array();
$results_2 = array();

while ($result1 = $rowSet1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $results_1[] = $result;
}

while ($result2 = $rowSet2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $results_2[] = $result;
}

var_dump($results_1, $results_2);
```

Comment: Since the queries are seemingly not dependend on each other, just untangle your code - completly processing the first query before executing the second.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [pdo::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method?

```
$results_1 = $rowSet1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results_2 = $rowSet2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That could take the place of both your while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop appends $result instead of $result2 to $results_2

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
while ($result1 = $rowSet1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $results_1[] = $result1;
}

while ($result2 = $rowSet2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $results_2[] = $result2;
}
```